# How can I write a routine to check, optimize and analyze all tables in databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I create a routine in MySQL to check, optimize and then analyse the tables?

Also how can I schedule this routine to run every night at set time?

Thanks

Comment: By "check, optimize, and analyse" are you referring to specific MySQL commands or general ideas?

Comment: @NickChammas the OP is referring to `CHECK TABLE tblname;`,`OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;`,`ANALYZE TABLE tblname;` commands in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer writing it myself. Place these lines in `/usr/local/sbin/OptimizeAllTables.sh`

```
WHICH=/usr/bin/which
MYSQL=`${WHICH} mysql`
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE ',db,'.',tb,';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb,engine eng"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE"
SQL="${SQL} engine in ('InnoDB','MyISAM') AND table_schema NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')"
SQL="${SQL} ORDER BY data_length DESC) A"
${MYSQL} ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > /tmp/OptimizeAllTables.sql
${MYSQL} ${MYSQL_CONN} < /tmp/OptimizeAllTables.sql
```

and make it executeable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/OptimizeAllTables.sh
```

## CAVEAT #1

Running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is the same as running `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=...` followed by `ANALYZE TABLE`. Therefore, there is no need to run a separate `ANALYZE TABLE`.

## CAVEAT #2

Please note I use `OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE` instead of `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. This ensures that the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is not recorded in the binary logs because it can replicate to Slaves. If you want the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to be replicated all Slaves, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is fine.

## CAVEAT #3

Note that I ordered all the tables by the biggest table first. If you want to optimize all tables starting with the smallest table, change this line

```
SQL="${SQL} ORDER BY data_length DESC) A"
```

to

```
SQL="${SQL} ORDER BY data_length) A"
```

## EPILOGUE

Simply place this line in the crontab to run every midnight

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/sbin/OptimizeAllTables.sh
```

If the tables are enormous, you may want to schedule this for one a week (Sunday at Midnight)

```
0 0 * * 0 /usr/local/sbin/OptimizeAllTables.sh
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you do not need to write your own script.

I would suggest reading about the mysqlcheck MySQL command. It has options to do all of the things that you want to do to a table, to all tables in a database, and so forth. The MySQL documentation on this can be found at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

In terms of scheduling the tasks MySQL has an Event Scheduler which can be used to manage the scheduling and running of events.  The MySQL documentation starts here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Original link posted was:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/